# gitlab ci error /bin/sh: eval: line 138: docker: not found

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

gitlab runner throws error when i trying to build docker image

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
container_scanning:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1

  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    FULL_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
    # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker build -t testdocker .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM 
Test.dev/devops/aquasec/trivy:0.16.0
RUN trivy filesystem --skip-update --exit-code 1 --no-progress /
```

**error**

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 138: docker: not found
$ docker build -t testdocker .
```

I have chcked the docker image history, the entry point is `ENTRYPOINT ["trivy"]`   :

```
~$ docker image history --no-trunc aquasec/trivy:latest
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED       CREATED BY                                                                                          SIZE      COMMENT
sha256:9a0e347a8cda3c2bdf3f4d7aa24ccfb3e5dce8763bf6064526fdecd06aafd711   4 days ago    ENTRYPOINT ["trivy"]                                                                                0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago    COPY contrib/*.tpl contrib/ # buildkit                                                              14.7kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago    COPY trivy /usr/local/bin/trivy # buildkit                                                          39.3MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago    RUN /bin/sh -c apk --no-cache add ca-certificates git # buildkit                                    13.5MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]                                                                  0B        
<missing>                                                                 7 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:aad4290d27580cc1a094ffaf98c3ca2fc5d699fe695dfb8e6e9fac20f1129450 in /    5.6MB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're telling GitLab to run the Pipeline within a container with the image `trivy` image, which I suppose it's a custom Dockerfile using `aquasec/trivy` as base image.

If you haven't installed the Docker CLI in your custom image, there is no reason for it to be there.

```
❯ docker pull aquasec/trivy
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from aquasec/trivy
a0d0a0d46f8b: Already exists
330bb1eb9af6: Pull complete
de4b3e2cc536: Pull complete
65a5529ac0a6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c5e2a98e1c1a34f2f6d80f02b4f78fb25ddafbadb8f2b3962059b14c8da1d6f8
Status: Downloaded newer image for aquasec/trivy:latest
docker.io/aquasec/trivy:latest
❯ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh aquasec/trivy
/ # docker --version
sh: docker: not found
```

If I scan that image with `docker scan` I can see it uses `alpine:3.14.2` as base image and `apk` as package manager; so, in order to use Docker within that container, your custom image (the one under `$CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1`) should have the Docker CLI installed.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM aquasec/trivy

RUN apk add docker-cli
```

And of course have defined in the Docker Runners configuration under `configuration.toml` that the used images perform a bind-mount of `/var/run/docker.sock`.

Another option is to use Docker-in-Docker (directly install the whole Docker within the container and start the daemon on it).

To use Docker in Docker you'd have to modify a little bit your job:

```
container_scanning:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1

  services:
    - docker:19.03.12-dind

  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    FULL_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon.
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
    # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance.
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # Disable TLS since we're running inside local network.
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

  script:
    - docker build -t testdocker .
```

Keep in mind that in case you decide to use Docker in Docker instead of actually mount the socket, you'll have the following limitations: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#limitations-of-docker-in-docker

Comment: Is dnid Docker-in-Docker built in in gitlab?  Just insert the services: - dnid ?

Comment: I am not sure where is this file configuration.toml so i cant check the content , am i must be a gitlab admin?

Comment: The `configuration.toml` isn't in GitLab, but is the configuration of the runner itself. Normally it's under `~/.gitlab-runner/configuration.toml` or `/etc/gitlab-runner/configuration.toml`, depending on which user do you use to execute the Runner.

Regarding `dind`, for using the service `dind` you still need to install the Docker CLI. When it sees that you don't have the default unix socket it will try to find it in `tcp://docker:2375`.

I will add the Docker-in-Docker option to my answer.

Comment: now the error is about $ docker build -t testdocker .
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /builds/test/eval-grype/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: my Dockerfile content is ""FROM $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1

RUN apk add docker-cli"" because no internet connection outside, i need to use the registry from nexus repo

Comment: ok i removed GIT_STRATEGY: none, seems ok, new error $ docker build -t testdocker .
Step 1/2 : FROM $CI_REGISTRY/devops/trivy/trivy:0.20.1
invalid reference format

Comment: finally it seems good. i cannot use gitlab prj variables $CI_REGISTRY in Dockerfile. i pasted the full path and works now.

Comment: Probably you haven't defined the `CI_REGISTRY` before using it. Since it's something that is only important for the build context, you could declare it as a build argument. Add `ARG CI_REGISTRY` before the `FROM` and call it from the CI/CD as `docker build --build-arg CI_REGISTRY=$CI_REGISTRY -t testdocker .` BTW, why do you want to build the `trivy` image?

Comment: the build image is just a trial (i should not use trivy but i only has this in nexus repo). once this works then i will have one build stage (to build image), then one stage test to scan it using trivy image. not sure if my logic sounds alright? pretty new to gitlab, try to figure out how it works with dockers.

Comment: the build is failed in the end, Status: Downloaded newer image for test.dev/devops/grype/grype:0.23
 ---> 849b7da4818c
Step 2/2 : RUN apk add docker-cli
 ---> Running in 1f26ac9f9be2
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: Of course it fails, you're trying to run `apk add` in a base image (`grype`) that is distroless, so it doesn't have a shell. If you want to learn about Distroless images, there is good documentation on the Google repos: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless#distroless-docker-images

Comment: got it. i thought the apk add is part of enabling docker. removed it and works now.

Comment: `apk` is the package manager of the `alpine` distributions. If you have a `debian` or `ubuntu` distribution, it's possible that you use `apt` and if you use OpenSUSE or SUSE you'll have `zypper` by default.